# Ordering <h:outputStyleSheet> and <link rel="stylesheet"> swapped

Tags: html, css, jsf, jsf-2.2, facelets

In my JSF 2.2 Facelet I have the following code:

```
<html  ... >
  <f:view>
    <h:head>  
       <h:outputStylesheet name="bootstrap-lib/css/bootstrap.css" />
       <h:outputStylesheet library="jquery-ui" name="css/jquery-ui.css" />
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="url.to.css" />
      ...
    </h:head>
    ...
  </f:view>
</html>
```

This outputs however:

```
<html ...>
  <head>
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="url.to.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href=".../javax.faces.resource/bootstrap-lib/css/bootstrap.css.xhtml?con=bootstrap" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href=".../javax.faces.resource/css/jquery-ui.css.xhtml?ln=jquery-ui&amp;con=bootstrap" />
    ...
  </head>
  ...
</html>
```

The sorting of the stylesheets defined in link and outputStylesheet are ignored and the 'outputStyleSheet' stylesheets are always placed last.

I need the "url.to.css" stylesheet defined with the 'link'tag as last in the list, so it will be dominant. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed with `@import`:

**Facelet**:

```
<html ...>
  <head>
    ...
     <h:outputStylesheet name="css/all.css" />
    ...
  </head>
  ...
</html>
```

**all.css**

```
@import url("#{resource['bootstrap-lib/css/bootstrap.css']}");
@import url("#{resource['jquery-ui:css/jquery-ui.css']}");
@import url("url.to.css");
```

Comment: I am retrieving my bootstrap.css via CDN. The respective link-tag looks like this: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"/>`. Is there a way to include the integrity validation when using `@import`?